# what is the correct way to add classes to a controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class

If i need to add (project specific) classes to my controler in rails, what is the correct way/place to put and "include" them/there .rb files? (quotes for: not the ruby keyword include)

I am new to rails, and did not find *the* correct way. LIB sounds like for more public libraries and - what I have learned - is not reloaded per default in dev mode.

sure, I could put all in controler.rb, but ...

---

the anser for me:

First: there are no rules, if you keep in mind (or learn like me) the rails rules:
NameOfCla -> name_of_cla(.rb)  <-- not using class as word for clearence

name your class how you like:

```
class ExtendCon #<--- not using controller here for clearence
    ....
```

put it in a file `extend_con.rb`, wait for the path explaination, please. if you named your class 'MYGreatThing' it will be 'm_y_great_thing' (never testet that), so avoid chineese charachters

if your controller uses

```
@letssee=ExtendCon.new
```

rails learns that class and file (extend_con) on its own. i still did not figure out if a server restart is needed. (the first time)

choose the path to put the file: (I preferre Daves way) `app/myexten` or what you like, making it 'app' specific and still distquishes to standard rails 'things'

if you are not lasy like me (i put it in app/ontrollers)
put the path you have choosen into 
`config/application.rb` like (comments are there to find it)

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/controllers)
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/myexten)
```

this one workes for me in all modes including "developer" and i did not need to put "my own" things in app/lib

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

I tend to put library code used explicitly (e.g., instantiated, injected, etc. into app-level artifacts) into `app/xxx` where `xxx` signifies the "type" of thing, like `decorators`, `services`, etc.

Magic stuff tends to end up in `lib`, like monkey patches, architectural-level artifacts, and so on.

Code anywhere can be added to the autoload paths, required automatically by an initializer, etc.

Comment: Why isnt there something like "rails add class[file] [in group] [etc]", that would sound stringent for me

Comment: @RolandMayer Probably because there's no good reason to be that stringent; IMO Rails shouldn't be that opinionated about how your code is organized.

Comment: your point, i am still fighting with, what is (automaticaly) reloded per request (in dev mode) and what not, so I thought telling RAILS "look, take this one, too", would be an idea

Comment: @RolandMayer Isn't that what `config.autoload_paths` is for?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 comes with an internal directory for controllers called concerns. You could try using that.

```
app/controlls/concerns
```

If you have `concerns/foo_bar.rb`, you include it as follows:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  include FooBar
end
```

Models also have their own concerns directory. I find this approach useful, and it can be applied to Rails 3. You just have to add the directories to your load paths.

Comment: i still "feel", that a rails 'add class ...' would be stringent, although dave above  has an an other opinion